# White space and digit 1 not being filtered in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using jquery datatable, i have some records in data table like data1, data2, data3. When i enter 1 in the filter, table is not filtered, but if i enter 2 or 3 its being filtered. I could not find the solution. Please help.

Thanks.